# Interoperability of Bitcoin clients

Tags: wallet, windows, android, ios, shared-wallet

Is it possible to operate on the same wallet from multiple devices? If I run, for example Android on a device, and Windows/Linux on another, how do I share the same private key(s) of my wallet between these device so I can send money from any of them?

Are the wallet files someway interoperable between clients? Is there a dedicated import/export tool?

I'm mainly interested in [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet) client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use online wallet, like [StrongCoin](https://strongcoin.com/), then it doesn't matter where you access it from.
2. You need to use an Android client that allows for private key import/export. I'm not sure which Android client does this, but for Windows/Linux you either can look for some tools for altering the wallet.dat for the standard Client, or use an alternative client with import functionality (as far as I remember, [MultiBit](http://multibit.org) can do that, but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: In the latest version of MultiBit you can import private keys in this format: https://github.com/jim618/multibit/wiki/Export%20and%20limited%20import%20of%20private%20keys . If you can export your private keys from your Android client in the sipa wallet import format you should be able to import them into MultiBit.

Comment: Note that the next release of the standard client will provide `dumpprivkey` and `importprivkey` RPC calls, so I can import and export private keys on the desktop wallet.  If the wallet on my phone allows the same then I can manually keep them in sync.  There's still the issue of 'change' addresses however; each time I make a spend, the change is sent back to a new address which I will need to sync to my other wallet(s).

Comment: @ThePiachu Is it true that StrongCoin keeps some of your "transaction fees" for themselves when you send coins to other addresses?

Comment: @Pacerier They charge a small amount on top of transaction fees.

Comment: @ThePiachu Are you aware how does it work? It states *"A fee of 1% will be added to the amount you send. The minimum fee is 0.005 BTC and the maximum is 1 BTC."* So if we send 1000 BTC how much is charged?

Comment: @Pacerier If you send 1000BTC, you would be charged 10BTC if it wasn't for the cap. So you will be charged 1BTC. You would probably be also charged about 0.0005 BTC of a standard transaction fee.

Comment: @ThePiachu Hmm, StrongCoin doesn't allow us to increase/decrease the standard transaction fee.

Comment: @Pacerier Nope, it follows standard client's transaction fees rules as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

[BitcoinSpinner](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.miracleas.bitcoin_spinner) for Android phones allows you to export your private key in the Sipa format. This allows you to import it in any wallet service that supports Sipa formatted private keys.